# How to find and print the repeated words in a text file from user input java

Tags: java

When I run the program, I would like to enter a word thats in the text file and have it print out how many times the word is stored in the text. For Example:

Enter a word from the text: eric

The word eric is stored 5 times in the text file.

My code below already reads the text file, but I am stuck on the wordCount method. I don't know how to start.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
public class WordSet {

    private static Scanner file;
    private static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    //private static Map<String, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //private static Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(words);
    //private static int tWords = 0;
    //private static int uWords = 0;

    //private static String [] word1 = new String[10];
    //private static String [] word2 = new String[10];

    public static void openFile() throws IOException {

        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
    }

    public static String wordCount() throws IOException {

        Random r = new Random();

        while(file.hasNext()) {
            words.add(file.next());
            }

        String wordCount = words.get(r.nextInt(words.size()));

        return wordCount;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Enter a word from the text: ");
        openFile();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String pickWord = wordCount();
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            String input = scan.nextLine();

            if(input.equals(pickWord)) {
                System.out.println(pickWord);
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your file have one word per line?

Comment: yes  it does @Shar1er80

Answer (score 0):

I would consider hashing and counting each word in file. The you just hash user input as well and if it's in the table return the count. It looks like you already were planning that.

Answer (score 0):

I have added taken input from command line and read ArrayList to give freq below is snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter a word from the text: ");
    openFile();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputStr = scan.next();
    Collections.frequency(words, inputStr);
    String pickWord = wordCount();
    System.out.println("You have entered '" + inputStr
            + "' frequency in text file is :"
            + Collections.frequency(words, inputStr));
    /*
     * while(scan.hasNext()) { String input = scan.nextLine();
     * 
     * if(input.equals(pickWord)) { System.out.println(pickWord); } }
     */
    scan.close();
}
```

Bu using Collections.frequency() u can count easily with less code... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help...I will try this @Joywish